# Visual Studio 2017 - Open in Visual Studio from Explorer - Permission Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS 2017 Enterprise.

I have it setup to open/run in Administrator mode which is working for SLN files.

However I'm trying out the new "Open in Visual Studio" feature by right clicking on a folder in Explorer. I'm receiving the following permission error. It's happening for every folder I try.

VS Code has no problem however.

Is there something more I need to enable?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also have the same issue in all my computers, using different versions of VS 2017. It is important to remember that this error happens ONLY when you choose this option on a Folder, not on a file. The error is not generated by VS, it is the explorer that throws this error.

Comment: @Daniel thanks. So I'm assuming you haven't figured out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that the VS 2017 application itself (devenv.exe) is configured on that machine to always Run as Administrator see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431742.aspx on how to change it:

> To mark an application to always run as an administrator, do the following: 
>   1. On the Start menu, locate the program that you want to always run as an administrator.  
>   2. Right-click the application’s shortcut, and then click Properties. 
>  
>   3. In the Properties dialog box, click the Compatibility tab.  
>   4. Do one of the following:  
>     - To apply the setting to the currently logged-on user, select the Run This Program As An Administrator check box, and then click OK.  
>     - To apply the setting to all users on the computer and regardless of which shortcut is used to start the application, click Change Setting For All Users to display the Properties dialog box for the application’s .exe file, select the Run This Program As An Administrator check box, and then click OK twice.

See also list of things that you can't do without administrator account https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj662724.aspx. What typically makes Web-developers to make VS always run as administrator is "Deploying a web application to Internet Information Services (IIS) on a local computer." and "Debugging applications that a run under a different user account, such as ASP.NET websites."

Answer (score 0):

For me it has worked as it should, at least this can help you.
First question is how you "setup to open/run in Administrator mode" ?

Using the "Advanced button" of the Visual Studio 2017 shortcut is not enough because methods with the right mouse button don't use this shortcut.

Using the method of the compatibility tab as mentioned already by SergGr
(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431742.aspx) has worked for me, and I have been able to use it for folders as well as for solution files !

I am logged in as a member of the local admin group and UAC standard setting into Win 8.1 .

Another possibility instead of using the compatibility page would be to inject an own manifest into devenv.exe. Neither of the two is very clean (I am no fan of the whole compat layer, but it helps here a bit).

Have you tried to switch UAC off temporarily for a test? Or how you have configured UAC?

If you have done it the way described, the explorer should come up with a correct UAC message.

[image]

Comment: UAC is already turned off unfortunately. Also I have VS set to run as administrator on load. This error only occurs when trying to open a folder through explorer. Open a solution works fine however.

Comment: @aherrick, what I say is that you probably should **_clear_** that setting because it is the reason for the error. However, the fact that UAC is turned off reduce chances that I'm right. Is your user actually a member of "Administrators" group?

Comment: @aherrick: Unfortunately, you just repeated the info from above. But first I wanted to know HOW you have set VS to run as administrator on load.. As I pointed out there are at least three different methods. For me, obviously, your system has a configuration problem. So it is necessary to change _something_. Your error message is heavily related to UAC, so when you say, you turned it off, something is really wrong on your system concerning rights/UAC configuration. So the second question is how you turned UAC off?

Comment: .. Maybe you try to reactivate UAC, at least temporarily, to find out what's different on your system? Because normally this works with UAC on perfectly. Is it possible that you used some Windows policy switches on your system for UAC instead of switching it off the "normal" way in the GUI ? Me, I haven't seen this error message since Vista.. (BTW, which Windows version you are using?)

Comment: I've just gone into UAC settings and moved the slider bar all the way to the bottom. I temporarily moved the back back up, still the same error. Moved it back down (turning it off) and stlil seeing it.

Comment: I've set devenv.exe to run as Administrator by going through the troubleshoot prompt. I just tried removing that setting, but I'm still seeing the error.

Comment: You rebooted? Because getting an error concerning UAC is quite unusual, if UAC disabled, I have no further idea. In fact, the logic behind the context menu is not really difficult, it just seems to look for an .sln file and opens this. So just strange that is doesn't work on your system.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me if not for you then refer to (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GregTrevellick.OpeninVisualStudio2017Enterprise):

**1.** open notepad.exe and paste this into it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VSCode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
```

here is my registry file exported just incase you need it (you shouldnt):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VSCode\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,5c,00,\
  4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,53,00,20,\
  00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00
```

**2.** save as `VSElevated.reg`

**3.** go to where you saved the .reg file and double click, yes to everything and ok.

**4.** This is how your Registry should look like afterwards:

[image]

The reason i think is the `%1` is missing in your launch command. This should solve it.

Comment: Hi. I'm confused on your answer. Are you referencing VS Code? The problem here is with VS2017